# DAte Format in Sybase

Tags: sap-ase

How can I convert a column of datetime data which stores value like this by default in Sybase

```
Sep 15 1999 12:23:56:230AM
```

to this format:

```
MM/DD/YY HH:MI:SS,FF9
```

I don't see any option for convert function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it yourself:

```
declare @test datetime
select @test = getdate()

select convert(varchar, @test, 1) + ' ' + convert(varchar, @test, 108) + ',FF9'
```